# Swift Alamofire: Error - 999

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am doing reuquest inside another request and get error -999 on the second one. I need this to keep same cookies received in first session and also because second request is optional.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

sessionManager.request( NSLocalizedString("url_login", comment: ""), method: .post, parameters: params).response{ response in
    if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            /..some elaboration../
            if(/..condition../){
            self.showMessage(message: "OK")
            sessionManager.request( NSLocalizedString("url_checkUserType", comment: ""), method: .get).responseJSON(){ response in
                 /..HERE I GET: finished with error - code: -999 ../
                 }

     }else{
            /..some other code../
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that variables `sessionManager`  and `NSLocalizedString` where not reachable from the launched thread. Solution make these variables **global** inside Controller and call them in the launched thread using `self.`.

Note that session manager should be declared like:
`var sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)`